# How to use CStr to convert generic parameter to String?

Tags: vb.net, string, generics, type-conversion

I wrote a generic `Sub` and need to convert the input values to `String` to get them into a `TextBox`(in this case a powerpoint textbox). This looks like:

```
Sub InsertValueIntoTextbox(Of t)(ByVal sldNr As Integer, ByVal tbName As String, ByVal valueToInsert As T)
    _pptSld = _pptPre.Slides(sldNr)
    _pptSld.Shapes(tbName).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CStr(valueToInsert)
End Sub
```

My problem is that it gives me this compiler-error:

> The value of t cannot be converted into string

I tried a `CStr` (as you can see in the snippet) but this doesnt help too. Could anyone help me get this to work and can tell me why I cannot convert `T` to `CStr`?

Comment: If you're always going to convert `valueToInsert` to String, why use a generic method at all?  Why not just make the parameter a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `Object` *can* [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx), so why dont you use that?

```
Dim text = If(valueToInsert Is Nothing, "", valueToInsert.ToString())
_pptSld.Shapes(tbName).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = text
```

You cannot use [`CStr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk841e9(v=vs.84).aspx) on generics. The type of the parameter must be convertible to `String` which is not guaranteed in your case. That's why you get the compiler error. I wouldn't use those old VB functions anymore. There are always .NET alternatives.

Comment: ah, this works. Could you tell me why .ToString works but CStr() doesnt? I just want to understand. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ruedi: i've already edited my answer. `CStr` exptects the parameter to be convertible to string, so not all objects are allowed. Only some like: Boolean, Date, Numbers, Nothing or String.